# Select field from recordset that is between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is an example as it is pretty difficult to explain:

Table one:

```
| Date        | Place ID |
==========================
| 01-Feb-2013 | 1        |
| 21-Jun-2015 | 2        |
```

Table two:

```
| Place ID | Date Ranked | Score |
==================================
| 1        | 01-Jan-2012 | 2     |
| 1        | 01-Jan-2014 | 1     |
| 1        | 01-Jan-2010 | 3     |
| 2        | 01-Jan-2016 | 1     |
```

What I want to happen is with SQL (MS) is when the first record of table one is returned I want whatever the score at that time to be returned from the second table. So in this example the score should be 2 as it is after 01-Jan-2012 but before 01-Jan-2014. And when the second record from table 1 is returned it should return NULL or blank from table 2 as no score existed for that time chosen.

Hope that makes sense!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.score
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.placeid = t1.placeid and
            t2.dateranked <= t1.dateranked
      order by t2.dateranked desc
     ) t2;
```

In this case, you can do the same thing with a correlated subquery as well.